# HTML Details/Summary Element Marker Styling

Tags: html, css

I have some CSS that styles the marker next to a summary element within a details element.  The CSS itself works fine.  However, if I nest another details element within the first one (creating a parent details element and a child details element), my marker content doesn't toggle properly.  As soon as I open the parent, the child marker shows as being open even though that element is not open yet.

I am not sure if there is a proper selector to isolate the child details element from the parent in this case since the child is not open and there is no [closed] syntax in CSS that I am aware of.  It appears than when nesting details elements, once the parent is open, all children are also "open". Has anyone run into something like this before?

```css
summary {
    outline: none;
    font-size: 1.15em;
}

summary::-webkit-details-marker {
    display: none
}

summary:after {
    background: #da291c;
    border-color: #da291c;
    border-radius: 15px;
    content: "+";
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: -2px 10px 0 0;
    padding: 1px 0 3px 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30px;
}

details[open] summary:after {
    content: "-";
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Parent</summary>
  <p>
    Parent Holder Text
  </p>
  <details>
    <summary>Child</summary>
    <p>
      Child Holder Text
    </p>
  </details>
</details>
```

Comment: Sorry... here is the fiddle with the code: https://jsfiddle.net/BrianCatt/bcnyku7h/4/

Comment: If  you could edit the code into your question that'd be great.

Comment: Edit your question and post your complete current code snippet there at the bottom by clicking the "JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet" icon.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your CSS is applying `content: "-";` to all `summary:after` elements within `details[open]`, so it cascades to children too. Try applying it to only direct children of the parent element with a [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) (`>`)

```
details[open] > summary:after {
    content: "-";
}
```

Answer (score 12):

```
details summary::-webkit-details-marker,
details summary::marker {
 display: none; 
 content: "";
}
```

if it doesn't work try this (::marker and content for chrome)

Answer (score 3):

```
details[open] > summary::marker {
    display: none;
    content: "";
}
```

If what you are interested in is hiding the element called summary, which is represented as an arrow, you must call it when with the speudoselector "marker", you must specify that you do not want it to be placed in any way. Therefore, as the "content" property has the function of graphing text, you should not specify anything, you will leave it empty (content: "") The code would be this =

Here i'll show the diference:

---

[Content-yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFWwe.png)

[Content-none](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgzEm.png)