# How to rotate pseudo-element on click in ReactJS and its content is SVG

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-selectors, pseudo-element

[images for my project]

**[1]**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6EFH.png

**[2]**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMhNu.png

when I click on the orange arrow I want to rotate it (180deg)

Is this can be done with CSS or I should use JS

And how I can declare a variable and give it a pseudo-element as a value in ReactJS

```
<div className="container">
        <div className="imgBox">
          <img src={img_1} alt="img_1" className="img_1" />
          <img src={img_2} alt="img_2" className="img_2" />
        </div>

        <div className="textBox">
          <h1>FAQ</h1>
          <div className="questions">
            <div>
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  hideText(p1);
                }}
              >
                How many team members can I invite?
              </button>
              <p ref={p1} className="p1 not-active">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
                Temporibus obcaecati, quae, corporis.
              </p>
            </div>

            <hr />

            <div>
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  hideText(p2);
                }}
              >
                How many team members can I invite?
              </button>
              <p ref={p2} className="p2 not-active">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
                Temporibus obcaecati, quae, corporis.
              </p>
            </div>

            <hr />

            <div>
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  hideText(p3);
                }}
              >
                How many team members can I invite?
              </button>
              <p ref={p3} className="p3 not-active">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
                Temporibus obcaecati, quae, corporis.
              </p>
            </div>

            <hr />

            <div>
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  hideText(p4);
                }}
              >
                How many team members can I invite?
              </button>
              <p ref={p4} className="p4 not-active">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
                Temporibus obcaecati, quae, corporis.
              </p>
            </div>

            <hr />

            <div>
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  hideText(p5);
                }}
              >
                How many team members can I invite?
              </button>
              <p ref={p5} className="p5 not-active">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
                Temporibus obcaecati, quae, corporis.
              </p>
            </div>

            <hr />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**Styling**

```
.container>.textBox>.questions>div>button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: transparent;
  color: var(--Very-dark-grayish-blue);
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.container>.textBox>.questions>div>button:hover {
  color: var(--Soft-red);
}

.container>.textBox>.questions>div>button:focus {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container>.textBox>.questions>div>button::after {
  content: url(./images/icon-arrow.svg);
  float: right;
}

.container>.textBox>.questions>div>button::after:focus {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't posted your markup, but you can do this a lot cleaner with just html/css using the `<details>` disclosure element. Read the MDN docs for that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

You have full control over the style of it including hiding the marker psuedo element. There's a specific answer for that in this thread which you will find useful: [HTML Details/Summary Element Marker Styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48814993/html-details-summary-element-marker-styling)

Here's a snippet to get started. I've made the arrow out of css too because I don't have your svg. You'll need to replace the contents of the `:after` selector with your background-image etc, and again for the `[open]` selector.

```css
details {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

details summary:after {
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
  border-right: 2px solid orange;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 7px;
  margin: 2px 0.5rem 0 0;
  float: right;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 7px;
}

details summary::-webkit-details-marker,
details summary::marker {
  display: none;
  content: "";
}

details[open]>summary:after {
  transform: rotate(-135deg) translate(-4px, -3px);
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Section title</summary>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</details>
```